# react client: websocket.js:83 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3009/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket' failed:

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, websocket, socket.io

i have a node backend using socket io

first in app.js initialize te app

```
const express = require("express")

const app = express()

module.exports = {
    app,
    express
}
```

then in io.js, i create the socket server

```
const { app } = require("./app");
const http = require("http");
const socketio = require("socket.io");
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

module.exports = io;
```

then in the server.js first i import the app.js for api calls then i import io.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { app, express } = require("./app");
const logger = require("./logger");

const io = require("./io");
```

then i simply add emit listen code in the server.js

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("we have a new connection");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("the socket disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("join", ({ user_id }, callback) => {
    // const notification = getListNotifications(user_id);
    // const popup = getUserPopup(user_id);
    // socket.emit("nofication", { popup: popup.count, notification });
    socket.emit("nofication", { popup: 3, notificaton: { a: 1 } });
    socket.join(user.room);
    callback();
  });
```

then i run the server.js file in dev mode nodemon server.js

Then in react i simply use socket.io

```
import io from "socket.io-client";

useEffect(() => {
    socket = io("ws://localhost:3009", {
      "force new connection": true,
      reconnectionAttempts: "Infinity",
      timeout: 10000,
      transports: ["websocket"],
    });

   

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);
```

it gives me this error in browser console

[image: browser console]

the server node.js console is receiving https protocol

[image: server node.js console]

i find out in other answers that it maybe some protocol issue.

happy to learn from you. Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you solve this problem (if so)?

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me that i was listening the server with app.listen which only recieves https protocol....but i have created a seperated ws server with the server variable which should listen to a port so that the server can receive ws connection...

better to use this library [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ws) will make work much easier...

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add the below line of code to your `index.js` file

```
const chatServer = require('http').Server(app);
const chatSockets = require('./config/chat_sockets').chatSockets(chatServer);

 and below lines of code to you config--> sockets.js


module.exports.chatSockets = function(socketServer){
   
    let io = require("socket.io")(socketServer, {
        cors: {
          origin: "http://localhost:8000",
          methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        }
      });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).